# jQuery UI dropping elements only in special areas

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a problem with jQuery UI's drag and drop. I create dynamically new elements which are placed on the screen in one of four areas. These elements are draggable and I can place them all over the screen. But I want that these elements can only be dropped on one of the three areas.

I created a full working example here: http://jsbin.com/enusu4/

By clicking the text in the red bordered area, a new element is created and placed in the green area `drop1`. This element should now only be droppable to one of the green areas (`drop1`, `drop2` or `drop3`), nowhere else. How can I do this?

Best Regards, Tim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564865/draggables-jquery-ui-disable-individual-div-on-droppable/4565398#4565398), with some modifications it could do what you want:
Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('.drag').draggable({
        revert: "invalid",
        scope: "items"
    });
    $('#droppable').droppable({
        scope: "items",
        // if you want to disable the dragging after drop un-comment this
/*
        drop: function(e, ui) {
            $(ui.draggable).draggable({"disabled":true});
        }
        */
    });
    $('#droppable2').droppable();
    $(':button').click(function() {
        var $box = $('<div class="drag">Drag me</div>');
        $('#cont').append($box);
        $box.draggable({
            revert: "invalid",
            scope: "items"
        });
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div><button type="button">Add box</button></div>
<div id="droppable">Drop here</div>
<div id="droppable2">Out of scope!</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="cont">
    <div id="draggable" class="drag">Drag me</div>
    <div id="draggable2" class="drag">Drag me</div>
</div>
```

[Example Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ifaour/7t9X9/2/)

EDIT:
Okay, here's an update:
Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    var dragOptions = {
        revert: "invalid",
        scope: "items",
        helper: "clone"
    }
    $('.drag').draggable(dragOptions);
    $('.droppable').droppable({
        scope: "items",
        drop: function(e, ui) {
            var $drop = $(this);
            $(ui.draggable).draggable({
                "disabled": true
            }).appendTo($drop);
        }

    });
    $('#droppable2').droppable();

    $(':button').click(function() {
        var $box = $('<div class="drag">Drag me</div>');
        $('#cont').append($box);
        $box.draggable(dragOptions);
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div><button type="button">Add box</button></div>
<div style="float: left;"><h3>Drop here:</h3>
    <div class="drop1 droppable"></div>
</div>
<div style="float: left;"><h3>Drop here:</h3>
    <div class="drop2 droppable"></div>
</div>
<div style="float: left;"><h3>Out of scope!</h3>
    <div id="droppable2"></div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="cont">
    <div class="drag">Drag me</div>
    <div class="drag">Drag me</div>
</div>
```

[Example Link 2](http://jsfiddle.net/ifaour/7t9X9/3/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I need that the left upper corner of the red elements are inside, because I have to save the coordinates relative to the drop area. So if I drag the element into the drop area the upper left corner is 0px / 0px. In your demo, the element is also dropped if I drag it a little bit outside of the drop area. I hope you understand what I mean... Better: I made a screenshot: http://img716.imageshack.us/img716/3473/droppedi.png You see that the element is dropped, but it the upper left corner is outside of the yellow area, and so I will have negative coordinates.

Comment: Okay, I have updated my answer..I guess this is a better approach. BTW inspired by jQueryUI Droppable [example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#photo-manager)

Comment: Oh sorry, the elements should be positioned at any position, it is a kind of whiteboard and it should be flexible in this way.

Comment: hmmm, you should have elaborated more..anyway, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ifaour/7t9X9/4/) is the closest i can get.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#dropable").droppable({
   hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
   drop: function (event, ui) {
       if ( $('.ui-state-hover').size() > 0){return false;}
       //TODO
   }
}
```

Comment: while this might solve the question including an explanation would help the op.