# jQuery - Drag of elements in areas - then not draggable any more

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have three div areas. Creating an element, which is `draggable()` with jQuery UI, I can drag it all over the screen. Dropping it in a special area, then I can not drag it any more.

I created a full working demo: http://jsbin.com/enusu4/2/

There you can create a draggable element which is placed into the left green area. Dragging it to the middle or right green area, I can not drag the element.

I increment the zIndex of the elements, but it does not work.

Does anyone can help me, what's wrong?

Best Regards.

Comment: you already asked a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574978/jquery-ui-dropping-elements-only-in-special-areas) almost similar to this one? why not updating the previous one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `z-index:-1;` for 2nd and 3rd divs.

Comment: I did this, but it does not work, see here: http://jsbin.com/enusu4/3/, Update: http://jsbin.com/enusu4/4/ it works in my demo, in my real project, it does not, because doing a `z-index: -1` the div areas are not visible anymore.

Comment: With a `z-index:0` I see the div areas, but my elements seems to lay behind dragging them to the 2nd or 3rd area. On the border, I see clearly that the element is behind (the border line is in front of the div area).

Comment: With this solution, it works. I can drag the elements also in the 2nd and 3rd div area, but: I want that the one I drag is on top. If I create one element (elem1) and then another one (elem2) and drag elem1 over elem2, elem1 is is in the background, but I want that the last dragged element is on top. This does not work anymore with your solution.

Comment: I solved it: http://jsbin.com/enusu4/6/ Now everythin is okay. I added a start and stop function which sets an increments the z-index.